"Signed into law" or "signed into laws" when referring to multiple legislative bills?
For example, if the president signed both Bill A and Bill B, which is correct:

The president signed Bill A and Bill B into law last Monday.
The president signed Bill A and Bill B into laws last Monday.


Cambridge dictionary says "law" is an uncountable noun in such contexts.

On the other hand, in U.S. English at least, I think you could correctly say either "Both Bill A and Bill B became law when the President signed them last Monday" (with "law" understood in a unitary sense) or "Both Bill A and Bill B became laws when the President signed them last Monday" (with "laws" understood in the sense of distinct pieces of enacted legislation). The treatment of "law" as unitary prevails in the wording that you give because (as FumbleFingers and TimR note in their answers) the particular wording "signed into law" is an idiomatic set phrase in English.

Signed into law is an idiom / set phrase that means a proposed law1 has been signed by a government official, making it official law.
It's similar to, for example, Criminals are people who break the law. In such usages, singular [the] law effectively refers to any and all laws.
Another set phrase is The law of the land, meaning all of the laws in force within a country or region.

1 Or multiple laws - here are hundreds if not thousands of written instances of were signed into law in Google Books.

"signed into law" (singular) is a set phrase and you would not use the plural, "signed into laws".
The noun law encompasses all extant laws.
To "sign (something) into law" means to make it an integral  part of the country's law.
